# Eclipse word wrap line number mismatching

Tags: eclipse, latex, word-wrap

I'm using Texlipse to edit some LaTeX files, so it is very helpful to have the line wrap functionality. The one (the only one I found) I'm using now is [Eclipse word-wrap plugin](http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/). However, the line numbers do not show correctly with this plugin.

[image: Line numbers]

How can I fix it?

Comment: This won't solve your problem because it doesn't work with Latex, but the Colorer plugin (http://colorer.sourceforge.net/) seems to do a slightly better job of managing the the line number with word wrapping.

Comment: Texlipse have its own build-in support for line wrapping. Maybe that works better. http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/wrapping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Word-Wrap plugin has this problem, as is stated at the bottom of the page you link to. There is no way around it.

This plug-in is only a quick hack to switch on the word wrap functionality of the text box widget that the Eclipse editors are build on top of, not a solid solution to the problem. Eclipse is not good with texts that need word wrap.

Answer (score 0):

As Google led me here first - I will provide an update on this 2 year old question:

This issue has been solved in another plugin which is based on word-wrap:
[Eclipse Word-Wrap Plug-In](http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/word-wrap/)

Additional remark: After the installation it might be needed to run eclipse with the "- clean" parameter to enable the LineNumbering fix (mentioned [here](http://blog.cdhq.de/archive/476#comment-60676))